# How can inverse of a function take a set as an input and give out another set as on output when the domain and codomain were sets of some integers?

Tags: measure-theory, functions

I have just started self-studying measure theory and have come across the definition of measurable function. Below is a screenshot from wikipedia:
[image: measurable function (wikipedia)]

Suppose I throw two die and observe the sum of the faces. Let $X$ be the sample space and $Y$ be the set of values representing the sum of the faces of two die.

Then, $X=\{(1,1),(1,2),...,(6,6)\}$ and $Y=\{2,3,4,...,12\}$.

Let the corresponding sigma-algebras be given by the respective power sets.

Given that the function  $f$ is defined from $X$ to $Y$, it should take any single element from $X$ as an input (e.g., $(1,2)$) and give out any single element from $Y$ as an output (e.g., $3$).

 Similarly, if $f^{-1}$ is defined as a function, then it should take any single element from $Y$ as an input and give out a single element from the domain of $f$ as an output.

However, in the wikipedia page, $f^{-1}$ takes a subset of $Y$ as an input and gives out a subset of $X$ as an output. I am confused as to when did the function start taking a set as input and throwing a set as an output.

I can see that $f^{-1}$ here cannot be defined as a function for the die example. But, I still don't understand how in other cases, it would have made sense.

Can someone explain either in general or using the die example mentioned above?

Background: Undergraduate level of calculus, matrix algebra and statistics. However, I am not very comfortable with metric spaces yet.

Comment: It's overloaded notation. For a function $f:A\to B$ and $C\subseteq A,D\subseteq B$, it means $f(C):=\{f(x)~|~x\in C\}$ and $f^{-1}(D):=\{x\in A~|~f(x)\in D\}$

Comment: To add to the above comment, I suggest you look up pre-images and images.

Comment: @Ssay do you mean just the basic definition of these? Or is there anything/source in particular you'd like to suggest?

Comment: @ShoaibAshraf Basic notions. $f(C)$ is called the image of $C$ under $f$. Meanwhile, $f^{-1}(D)$ is called the pre-image of $D$ under $f$.

Comment: understood. Thank you.